# No periods at beginning or end of expression?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I want to allow alphanumeric characters and periods; however, the phrase cannot contain more two or more periods in a row, it cannot start or end with a period, and spaces are not allowed.

I am using both PHP and Javascript.

So far, I have `/^(?!.*\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/`

This works for allowing alphanumeric characters and periods, while denying spaces and consecutive periods, but I still am not sure how to check for starting and/or ending periods. How might I do this? and, is there an even better way to do what I already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a possible way

```
/^(?!\.)((?:[a-z\d]|(?<!\.)\.)+)(?<!\.)$/i
```

for more explanations and tests see here: http://www.regex101.com/r/rZ6yH4

edit: according to tyler's solution, here's him way, shortened and reduced to letters and digits

```
/^(?:[a-z\d]+(?:\.(?!$))?)+$/i
```

( http://www.regex101.com/r/dL5aG0 )

Comment: This works perfectly well with every situation I've tested so far (note, I'm using the second of the two.) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

It nearly always helps to draw a finite state machine to conceptualize what your regular expression should look like.

```
^(?:\w\.?)*\w$
```

Comment: With `\w`, `\d` is redundant. And the negative look-ahead assertion seems redundant to me.

Comment: @nhahtdh, Ah, that regex was a stream of thought thing and I guess I didn't bother to check if it was in its most simple form. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A start would be:

```
/^[^. ](?!.*\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9.]+[^. ]$/
```

but it should be tested carefully.

Comment: this would allow any char,.. there's a dot inside the square brackets. you've to escape dots!

Comment: @bukfixart: `.` inside `[]` is just a dot, it doesn't have special meaning.

Comment: @bukfixart -- no, not inside square-brackets.  There you only have to escape up-carets and hyphens.  Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.