# Regular expression X characters long, alphanumeric but not _ and periods, but not at beginning or end

Tags: javascript, regex

As the subject indicates, I am in need of a JavaScript Regular expression X characters long, that accepts alphanumeric characters, but not the underscore character, and also accepts periods, but not at beginning or end. Periods cannot be consecutive either.

I have been able to almost get to where I want to be searching and reading other people's questions and the answers here on Stack Overflow ([such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142798/no-periods-at-beginning-or-end-of-expression)).

However, in my case, I need a string that has to be exactly X characters long (say 6), and can contain letters and numbers (case insensitive) and may also include periods.

Said periods cannot be consecutive and also, cannot start, or end the string.

`Jd.1.4` is valid, but `Jdf1.4f` is not (7 characters).

```
/^(?:[a-z\d]+(?:\.(?!$))?)+$/i
```

is what I have been able to construct using examples from others, but I cannot get it to only accept strings that match the set length.

```
/^((?:[a-z\d]+(?:\.(?!$))?)+){6}$/i
```

works in that it now accepts nothing less than 6 characters, but it also happily accepts anything longer as well...

I am obviously missing something, but I do not know what it is.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check the length separately (like, foo.length == 6)?

Comment: Try this regex: `/^[a-z\d](?![^.]*[.]{2})[a-z\d.]{4}[a-z\d]$/i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
/^(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z\d][a-z\d.]{4}[a-z\d]$/i
```

Explanation:

```
^             // matches the beginning of the string
(?!.*?\.\.)   // negative lookahead, only matches if there are no
              // consecutive periods (.)
[a-z\d]       // matches a-z and any digit
[a-z\d.]{4}   // matches 4 consecutive characters or digits or periods
[a-z\d]       // matches a-z and any digit
$             // matches the end of the string
```

Comment: This accepts 'j....f' as a valid match. [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/kpBab/). The author said 'Periods cannot be consecutive either.'

Comment: Mmh right... let me think about it. *edit:* Mixed up the lookhead syntax. Fixed, it should work now.

Comment: This seems to do the trick. One of those things where it makes sense _now_. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do that:

```
/(?=.{6}$)^[a-z\d]+(?:\.[a-z\d]+)*$/i
```

explanation:

```
      (?=.{6}$)   this lookahead impose the number of characters before 
                  the end of the string
      ^[a-z\d]+   1 or more alphanumeric characters at the beginning
                  of the string
(?:\.[a-z\d]+)*   0 or more groups containing a dot followed by 1 or 
                  more alphanumerics
              $   end of the string
```

Comment: Based on a couple of tests, the regex matches the J by itself if the string is something like: J..14a

Comment: @Magro284: Corrected: i have forgotten the final $

Comment: I like this solution a lot. Clean and makes sense to my way of thinking.